# Improve query performance in Rails when creating a json

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm working with a Rails 5 API. I have a simple model of a store, with:

```
order has_one checkout
checkout has_one transaction
checkout belong_to order
transactions belongs_to checkout
checkout has_many items

      1   1           1    1
order -----> checkout ------> transaction
                      1    *
                      ------> item
```

I want and endpoint that given an amount of the transactions, it returns a json with data from the transactions.

I have this code that works but it takes a lot of time. For example, a month worth of transactions it's taking 1 minute.

```rb
def get_all_transactions
  transactions = Transaction.where.not(status: 'error')

  data = transactions.map do |transaction|
    checkout = transaction.checkout
    order = Order.find(checkout.order_id)

    checkout.items.map do |item|
      {
        checkout_id: checkout.id,
        order_id: checkout.order_id,
        item_id: item.id,
        client_name: checkout.client.full_name,
        order_created_at: order.created_at
      }
    end
  end

  data.flatten!
end
```

How can I improve this code to have a better performance?

I have also notice that removing for example, the `checkout.client.full_name` it takes like 20 seconds off.

With full_name being in the client model:

```rb
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}".strip
end
```

Why would that take 20 seconds?

Comment: Look into eager loading, it is usually done as in e.g. `Order.where(...).includes(:checkout, :transactions)` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Sorry! I updated the question. I do use Order. I will look into eager loading.

Comment: I have tried doing eager loading, but it actually takes longer. @Eyeslandic

Comment: What are you passing into the method as `transactions`?  Are you running a query to get the transactions and then passing them into the method where you then make queries on every pass? Maybe making one query that gets all of the data you need and then pass that into the method to transform the data?

Comment: @Beartech "Are you running a query to get the transactions and then passing them into the method where you then make queries on every pass?" Yes, I'm doing this. I update the question to reflect that. Would that have a big impact in the performance? I did try to do that at the beginning but was not successful

Answer (score 0):

The problems here is that you have layers upon layers of [N+1 queries](https://blog.devgenius.io/avoiding-the-n-1-query-problem-in-rails-2f571f9e57e5). Every time you call an association that hasn't been eager loaded you're causing another round trip to the database. Even if you add `includes` or `eager_loads` then the next issue is that you're loading tons off data of the tables that you're not using and creating model instances in memory just to use a single attribute off them.

The most efficient way to do this is most likely going to be to simply perform a join and just select the columns you're actually interested in:

```
sql = Item.joins(order: { checkout: :client })
    .select(
       Item.arel_table[:id].as('item_id'),
       Order.arel_table[:id].as('order_id'),
       "TRIM(CONCAT(clients.first_name, ' ',  clients.last_name)) AS client_name",
       Order.arel_table[:created_at ].as('order_created_at') 
    )
result = Item.connection.select_all(sql.arel).map(&:to_h)
```

This avoids creating entire models instances in memory in multiple levels when all you need is a single column.

However its very unclear what the actual expected result is here or why you're basing the query off the Transaction model when you're actually getting an array of items in the result.

Comment: Side note - assuming that everyone uses `Firstname Lastname` is culturally insensitive and naive. https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/